# Construction of Thom classes via the Poincaré Duality Theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes

In Volume 1 of Spivak, the Poincaré isomorphism for a connected oriented n-manifold

$PD: H^k(M) \to H_c^{n-k}(M)^*$

is given by

$PD(\alpha)(\beta) = \alpha \cup \beta \in H_c^{n}(M) \cong \mathbb{R}.$

Where the latter isomorphism comes from taking the unique member $\eta \in H_c^{n}(M)$ satisfying

$\int_{M,\mu} \eta = 1$

to 1 (where $\mu$ is the orientation of $M$).

Spivak first constructs Thom classes for an orientable $k$-bundle $\xi: E \to M$ by claiming that there is a unique $U \in H_c^{k}(E)$ with

$\pi^*\eta \cup U = \nu \in H_c^{n+k}(E)$,

where $\eta$ is the compact orientation class on $M$, $\pi$ is the fibration, and $\nu$ is the compact orientation class on $E$.

This appears to me like choosing a vector from a non one-dimensional vector space to attain a value under a given functional, and I do not see the uniqueness or how this follows from the Poincaré Duality Theorem.

Comment: It is just Poincaré Duality if you use another duality: $H^k_c(E) \cong (H^n(E))^*$ (I'm using finite-dimensionality here, of course). Of course, doesn't Spivak go on to construct it more or less concretely in terms of generators of the compact cohomology of the fiber?

Comment: Oh, $H^n(E) \cong H^n(M)$ by contractibility so it is one dimensional, and I realize now that this argument used Poincaré duality. I was stuck on this for way too long without reading the following theorem which laid it out clearly at the end. Thanks.